# what is BOOST_ROOT?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build x64 version of http://code.google.com/p/quickfast/
That's how build scripts use %BOOST_ROOT%:

```
set SETUP_CHECKING=BOOST_ROOT=%BOOST_ROOT%
if not exist "%BOOST_ROOT%\boost" goto setup_is_bad

includes += $(BOOST_ROOT)/include

set RELEASE_PATH=%QUICKFAST_ROOT%\bin;%QUICKFAST_ROOT%\Output\Release;%MPC_ROOT%;%BOOST_ROOT%\lib;
```

So build script expects following file/folders:

```
%BOOST_ROOT%\boost
$(BOOST_ROOT)/include
%BOOST_ROOT%\lib
```

I've downloaded/builded boost and there are no `lib` or `include` folder. That's what my `boost` folder contains:

```
C:\bin\boost_1_49_0

14.03.2012  11:59    <DIR>          .
14.03.2012  11:59    <DIR>          ..
13.03.2012  16:17           249 856 b2.exe
13.03.2012  16:18    <DIR>          bin.v2
13.03.2012  16:17           249 856 bjam.exe
22.02.2012  18:25    <DIR>          boost
30.01.2012  21:30               866 boost-build.jam
30.01.2012  21:30             1 054 boost.css
30.01.2012  21:30             6 308 boost.png
30.01.2012  21:30            18 606 boostcpp.jam
30.01.2012  21:30             2 545 bootstrap.bat
13.03.2012  16:17             2 496 bootstrap.log
30.01.2012  21:30            10 324 bootstrap.sh
22.02.2012  18:05    <DIR>          doc
30.01.2012  21:30               794 index.htm
29.01.2012  16:58             5 556 index.html
30.01.2012  21:30               298 INSTALL
29.01.2012  16:58            10 423 Jamroot
22.02.2012  18:06    <DIR>          libs
30.01.2012  21:30             1 361 LICENSE_1_0.txt
13.03.2012  16:37             4 781 log.txt
22.02.2012  18:28    <DIR>          more
13.03.2012  16:17                76 project-config.jam
30.01.2012  21:30             2 757 rst.css
13.03.2012  16:18    <DIR>          stage
22.02.2012  18:24    <DIR>          status
22.02.2012  18:28    <DIR>          tools
```

Where can I find x64 boost version that contains `lib` `include` and `boost` folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include files are in folder `%BOOST_ROOT%\boost`
Libraries are in `%BOOST_ROOT%\libs`

Change your build script accordingly.

Example:

```
%BOOST_ROOT%: c:\bin\boost_1_49_0
Includes: %BOOST_ROOT%\boost
Libs: %BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib
```

Comment: my `libs` folder contains a lot of other folders but no libs

Comment: The sources of the libs are in `%BOOST_ROOT%\libs`. The build libs themself are in `%BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib`

Comment: `stage` contains `lib` folder but doesn't contain `include` or `boost` folder :( so it is not clear where to point %BOOST_ROOT%

Comment: thanks, and where is dll files that I should use in my program? for example something like `boost_system-vc100-mt-1_43.dll` ?

Comment: If you need DLLs instead of LIBs then you have to build Boost differently I guess.