# cmake troubles with path to Includes And Libraries

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, casablanca

i try to cross-compile my app to Raspberry Pi with docker.

1. I built image with necessary dependencies from armhf architecture (protobuf-compiler-grpc:armhf libgrpc-dev:armhf libgrpc++-dev:armhf libprotobuf-dev:armhf libcpprest-dev:armhf libboost-dev:armhf). dependencies installed via apt-get from port.ubuntu.com repo.
2. After starting cmake with following args:

> ./cross-rpi-final cmake -DCASABLANCA_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/cpprest
>   -DCASABLANCA_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/include/boost -DProtobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DGRPC_ROOT_DIR=/usr -DGRPC_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/grpc -DGRPC_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DGRPCPP_UNSECURE_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DGPR_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DGW_CORE_LINUX_FIND_GRPC_AND_PROTOBUF_WITHOUT_CMAKE_CONFIGS=ON app-gw-linux

Part of required libs is find by cmake, but Casablanca and Boost is not found.

Output after cmake execution:

```
-- Version: 1.6.1.2, Rev: 64730c0
  + lib-gw-core-linux
  + lib-gw-core
  + commons
Configure as multiple libs
  + core
  + transport
   + rules engine
  + json11
  + gw-core
  + gw-core-linux-dev-console
  + cxxopts
  + tinyb
patching file /work/app-gw-linux/lib-gw-core-linux/tinyb/src/CMakeLists.txt
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
CMake Warning at lib-gw-core-linux/tinyb/CMakeLists.txt:26 (message):
   - Install git to compile a production libtinyb!


INFO - libtinyb Version v0.5.0-dirty
  + gw-core-linux
-- Could NOT find Casablanca, try to set the path to Casablanca root folder in the system variable CASABLANCA_ROOT_DIR (missing: CASABLANCA_LIBRARIES) 
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:163 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:163 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:163 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:163 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:425 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:176 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:431 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:176 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:432 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000 % 1000": syntax error,
  unexpected exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or
  exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:176 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:433 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " % 1000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_MOD, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:176 (find_package)


CMake Warning at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version 3.0.0 doesn't match library version ..
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:176 (find_package)


-- Using protobuf 
-- Using gRPC 
-- SOURCE FILES  include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBleScanner.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBleScanner.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBluetoothAdapter.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBluetoothAdapter.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBluetoothDevice.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxBluetoothDevice.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxGatt.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxGatt.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxCharacteristic.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/bt/LnxCharacteristic.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/DevicesListenerImpl.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/DevicesListenerImpl.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/App.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/App.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalApp.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalApp.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/SimpleTerminalApp.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/SimpleTerminalApp.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandEnvironment.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandEnvironment.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandInteractiveCloneable.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandInteractive.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandInteractive.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandMeta.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandMeta.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/SwitchOnOff.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/SwitchOnOff.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/RequestDispatcher.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandDataEvent.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Rename.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Rename.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/GatewayInfo.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/GatewayInfo.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Help.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Help.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Welcome.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Welcome.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Login.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Login.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Logout.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/Logout.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/cmd/CommandLauncherDefault.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Login.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Login.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Logout.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Logout.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Switch.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Switch.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Rename.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/Rename.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/RenameCommand.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/RenameCommand.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/SwitchCommand.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/SwitchCommand.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/LogoutCommand.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/LogoutCommand.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandResultDefault.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandResultDefault.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/LoginCommand.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/LoginCommand.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GatewayInfo.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GatewayInfo.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GatewayInfoCommand.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GatewayInfoCommand.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandsInvoker.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandsInvoker.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandWrapper.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandRemote.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandContext.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/CommandContext.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GrpcServer.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GrpcServer.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GrpcClient.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GrpcClient.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GWServiceImpl.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/GWServiceImpl.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/rpc/ServiceCommandsSender.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalAppClient.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalAppClient.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/Credentials.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/Urls.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalAppService.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/TerminalAppService.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/LnxEnvironment.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/LnxEnvironment.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/LnxBatteryStateMonitor.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/app/LnxBatteryStateMonitor.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/storage/LnxKeyValueStorage.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/storage/LnxKeyValueStorage.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/io/IOUtils.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/io/IOUtils.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/http/LnxHttpClient.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/http/LnxHttpClient.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/http/LnxHttpCall.cpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/http/LnxHttpCall.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/cloud/aws/AwsCloudClient.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/cloud/aws/AwsCloudClient.hpp;src/milfei/gw/core/lnx/cloud/LnxCloudClientFactory.cpp;include/milfei/gw/core/lnx/cloud/LnxCloudClientFactory.hpp;/work/lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/gwservice.pb.cc;/work/lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/gwservice.grpc.pb.cc
  + aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /work/third_party/rapidjson/download
[100%] Built target rapidjson
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Doxygen
 * Git

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * Protobuf
 * gRPC
 * PkgConfig
 * OpenSSL
 * Threads

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * SharedLibrary, build the library as shared objects
 * Cli, the command line interface
 * Samples, example programs making use of the SDK
 * Tests, unit and integration tests
 * Docs, HTML based API documentation

-- The following REQUIRED packages have not been found:

 * Casablanca
 * Boost

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/work/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/work/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Maybe reason of this trouble its a libraries of another architecture (armhf)? Host where placed crosscompiling container is server with AMD64 arch.

How i can set path to all libraries correctly and fix this problem?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 4.7) project(app_gw_linux VERSION
1.6.1.2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

option(APP_GW_LINUX_MOCK_BLUETOOTH "Use mock bluetooth API" Off)

if (APP_GW_LINUX_MOCK_BLUETOOTH)
    set(GW_CORE_LINUX_MOCK_BLUETOOTH On CACHE BOOL "Use mock bluetooth API" FORCE) endif ()

set(APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_MAJOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}) set(APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_MINOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}) set(APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_PATCH ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}) set(APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_TWEAK ${PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK})

find_package(Git) if(GIT_FOUND AND EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    # Get the latest abbreviated commit hash of the working branch
    execute_process(
            COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse --short HEAD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_REVISION
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    ) else()
    message(WARNING "Git not found, cannot set version info")
    SET(APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_REVISION "unknown") endif()

message(STATUS "Version: ${PROJECT_VERSION}, Rev: ${APP_GW_LINUX_VERSION_REVISION}") message("  + lib-gw-core-linux") add_subdirectory(lib-gw-core-linux)

include_directories(src
        lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/include)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/milfei/gw/lnx/Main.cpp)

add_executable(app-gw-linux ${SOURCE_FILES}) install(TARGETS app-gw-linux DESTINATION local/bin COMPONENT bin) install(FILES app-gw-linux.service DESTINATION /etc/systemd/system COMPONENT bin) install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/certs/verisign-class-3-public-primary-ca-g5.pem DESTINATION /etc/company/.agilegateway RENAME ca.pem COMPONENT bin) set(TARGET_NAME app-gw-linux)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/certs $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${TARGET_NAME}>/certs) target_link_libraries(app-gw-linux gw-core-linux)

if (NOT APP_GW_LINUX_MOCK_BLUETOOTH)
    target_link_libraries(app-gw-linux tinyb) endif ()

SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB") set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON) SET(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL "bin") SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "app-gw-linux") SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}) SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}) SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}) SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_TWEAK ${PROJECT_VERSION_TWEAK}) SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_TWEAK}") SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "support@company.com") SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "company.com") SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libcpprest2.10 | libcpprest2.9, libgrpc3 (>= 1.10), libgrpc++1 (>= 1.10)") SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/postinst;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/preinst;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/prerm;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debian/postrm") INCLUDE(CPack)
```

UPD. Boost output with debug log:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1121 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1123 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1125 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1127 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = OFF
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1199 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1201 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /usr/local/boost
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1203 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/boost/include/boost
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1205 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /usr/local/boost/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1207 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1282 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1284 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/local/boost/include/boost;/usr/local/boost/include;/usr/local/boost;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1286 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1416 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1426 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1502 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1504 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1567 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/boost/lib;/usr/local/boost/lib;/usr/local/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/local/boost/lib;/usr/local/boost/lib;/usr/local/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:165 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:165 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:587 (message):
  Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
  (all versions older than 1.33)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:950 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:165 (find_package)


-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc-mt-;boost_system-gcc-mt;boost_system-mt-;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc-mt-d-;boost_system-gcc-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-gcc-mt-;boost_chrono-gcc-mt;boost_chrono-mt-;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-gcc-mt-d-;boost_chrono-gcc-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d-;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc-mt-;boost_thread-gcc-mt;boost_thread-mt-;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc-mt-d-;boost_thread-gcc-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:165 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:425 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:182 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:431 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:182 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:432 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 1000 % 1000": syntax error,
  unexpected exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or
  exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:182 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:433 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " % 1000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_MOD, expecting exp_PLUS or exp_MINUS or exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER
  (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:182 (find_package)


CMake Warning at lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/cmake/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version 3.0.0 doesn't match library version ..
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib-gw-core-linux/gw-core-linux/CMakeLists.txt:182 (find_package)
```

And Toolchain config:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(cross_triple "arm-linux-gnueabihf")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{CC})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{CXX})
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER $ENV{FC})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{CROSS_ROOT} $ENV{CROSS_ROOT}/libc/usr)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR /usr/bin/qemu-arm)
```

Comment: If prefer to use [conan](https://conan.io/) for this. With conan you can easily build missing libraries. It will set the paths for you.

Comment: Can you post your `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: Jose Fernando Lopez Fernandez, pasted CMakeLists.txt in edited post.

Comment: From the errors, it looks like you need to specify where Casablanca and Boost are, which you can do by using [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html), [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395880/cmake-set-default-search-path), setting the [BOOST_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697926/what-is-boost-root), etc.

Comment: I start cmake with parameters:
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/local/boost/include/boost -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/local/boost/lib -DProtobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DGRPC_ROOT_DIR=/usr -DGRPC_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/grpc -DGRPC_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DGRPCPP_UNSECURE_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DGPR_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -DGW_CORE_LINUX_FIND_GRPC_AND_PROTOBUF_WITHOUT_CMAKE_CONFIGS=ON app-gw-linux

And cmake doesn't see boost :(

Comment: I am crosscompile boost from sources for arm arch. 

Also i'm add debug output for boost lib in main post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i just changed path $ENV{CROSS_ROOT}/libc/usr to /usr and all works fine.