# Building a cmake project which uses boost with a local distribution

Tags: boost, cmake

I'm trying to build kenlm which uses boost. The version of boost already installed on the system seems incompatible or too old or broken.

I have successfully built a copy of boost in my `~/local directory`. I would like to tell cmake to use the boost headers found under `~/local/include` and the libraries in `~/local/lib` instead. However I can't see how to tell cmake to look at my custom path for libraries or headers. I've tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `~/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Is there an equivalent variable for include path as well? I haven't been able to find one.

If there is no way to do this with just environment flags, I've been trying to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file but haven't had much success. I tried editing in my include path but it still uses whatever `find_package(Boost ..)` finds which is the `/usr/include` header.

Comment: Set(Boost_ROOT absolute_path_to_local_lib) then call find_package(). See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697926/what-is-boost-root

Comment: @vpa1977 thanks, it says 'CMake variable Boost_ROOT is set to: /home/tensorfoo/local' For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.' I changed it to BOOST_ROOT and i think it's working now. Cheers.

Comment: Boost cowardly treats the setting as a hint. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html . Use (set Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON) to force it to listen to you. PS. Docs do not say that it is deprecated . What version of cmake are you using ?

Comment: It's version 3.17.5 - so even after it warns, it still uses it but i had to change it to BOOST_ROOT instead of Boost and that did the trick. Appreciate it!

Comment: Oh. sorry ;( unintended phone capitalisation ;(